# [Zend_Form][1.11.1] Error Message Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Form_Login' not found in ...\modules\default\controllers\IndexController.php

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework

I don't speak english fluently (i'm french) so i will be 
i followed the tutorial [here](http://www.codeunit.co.za/2011/04/01/how-to-create-a-zend-framework-project-that-uses-modules/) and i got this structure

```
Application
--Modules
------admin
---------controller
---------views
------etat
---------controller
---------views
------default
---------controller
---------views
--configs
bootstrap.php
```

My problem is that, when i created my first form and tried to view it in my browser, i got the following error:

**Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Form_Login' not found in C:\wamp\www\get\application\modules\default\controllers\IndexController.php on line 14**.

Here is my code:

My controller : `/modules/etat/controller/IndexController.php`

```
class Etat_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
        $form = new Etat_Form_InfoAgent();
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }
}
```

My form :  `/modules/etat/forms/InfoAgent.php`

```
class Etat_Form_InfoAgent extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */
        $this->setName('infoagent');
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $login = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('matricule');
        $login->setLabel('Matricule:');
        $login->setRequired(true);
        $login->addFilter('StripTags');
        $login->addFilter('StringTrim');
        $this->addElement($login);

        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('agence');
        $password->setLabel('Code agence:');
        $password->setRequired(true);
        $password->addFilter('StripTags');
        $password->addFilter('StringTrim');
        $this->addElement($password);

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Valider');
        //$submit->style = array('float: right');
        $this->addElement($submit);       
    }


}
```

My view : `/modules/etat/view/script/index.phtml`

```
<br /><br />
<div id="view-content">
    <?php echo $this->form; ?>
</div>
```

Configuration file : `configs/application.ini`

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

;Modular structure
resources.modules[] =

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"

;database ressources
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = 
resources.db.params.dbname = bd_test

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

I have searched the web for solution but i didn't get it. I saw a post about the same problem on your website (stackoverflow) and i tried to aplly your instructions without solving my problem.
i precise that i haven't change the code on my bootstrap and my `public/index.php` file

I hope you could help me soon.
thx

Comment: Have you tried placing the form file in `/application/forms`?

Comment: thanks mingos,i tried to copy the forms folder in /application and i still get an error!

Comment: But are you positive the file and class naming is OK? The error you get seems to point to a class that is not in the code snippet. Also, the application.ini has a namespace defined, which your classes lack. Either revise the question to provide more accurate info, or tidy up your code to make sure you don't have a misnamed class or a misplaced file.

Comment: Hello, i m facing the same problem? did you get any solution? if any please give me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created a `Bootstrap.php` in each module directory, which looks like:

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{}
```

In which `Admin` is the name of the module.
Also, make sure there is actually a file `Login.php` inside directory `modules/admin/forms` with a class `Admin_Form_Login`